# Rotation of an Image on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sir,

In my HTML page, there is an image and two buttons for rotating that image clockwise and anticlockwise directions. And also I need to make draggable that image. I have the codes for doing both dragging and rotation.

I used the following JavaScript for Drag:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Image1').draggable();
        $('#WaterMark').draggable();
    });
</script>
```

And I used following JavaScript for rotation:

```
<script type="text/javascript"                 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var angle = 0;
    $('#btnRotCw').on('click', function () {
        angle += 2;
        $("#Image1").rotate(angle);
    });
    $('#btnRotAcw').on('click', function () {
        angle -= 2;
        $("#Image1").rotate(angle);
    });
});
</script>
```

But here the rotation is not happening.

Can anyone guide me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qLde61p2/)**

```
var angle = 0;
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    angle += 90;
    $("#image").rotate(angle);
});
$('#button1').on('click', function() {
    angle -= 90;
    $("#image").rotate(angle);
});
```

I am sure this can help to do what you want. Good luck

Comment: Sir, I copied the code from the link to an html page. But the image is not rotating. Can you help me please?

Comment: I didn't loaded the jquery for rotation. Now its working fine. Thank you very much for your valuable time.